# Django query with annotate and select related together

Tags: django, database, model

I'm unsuccessfully trying to google the solution for this simple case:

There are Book and Author models. I can have several same books (with different IDs).
Author is a foreign key within Book.

I need simple way how to list all books, their count and author name.

I can do:

`Book.objects.values("book_name","author").annotate(count=Count("book_name")`

which gives me an array where aditional value with count of "book_name" items. But instead of author name it returns just Author object id.

I can get author name using

```
Book.objects.select_related()
```

Which replaces the author's ID with related object so I can get the author.name but it doesn't work with `.values()`

Any idea how to get this working together? so I can have both count of each Book and author name?

I'd like to avoid complex solution like querying Books, and within the loop construction of a result array and querying Authors name for each book.

Thanks a lot.
TC

Comment: Can you share your models.py file? we need more info to help you .. It seems that your query structure is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select_related` is a total red herring here; it is *never* needed to access the elements of a related model, all it does is make that more efficient.

As with all other types of queries, to access the related elements you just use the double-underscore syntax. Assuming your Author model has a `name` field:

```
Book.objects.values("book_name","author__name").annotate(count=Count("book_name")
```

Note, I'm finding it hard to understand what your query is; what is the count of book names supposed to do? I suspect what you actually want is a list of author names and a count of their books, in which case you should start from Author not Book.)

Comment: Thanks, will try asap. Meantime let me clarify my case. I can have several identical copies of one book so I need to know how many of them I have. (I know I can use a new field count_of_books - by in reality they are HW devices with different part numbers but the same type.)

Comment: Thanks a lot - it works perfect - I didn't know about that double underscore approach ;)